# Firebase Database saving data after approvement

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using firebase database on an iOS app! I'm writing in swift. I'm using a 'Send' button to write data (ex. textField and label values) on my firebaseDatabase. Is there any way to accept or decline data on my database? What I mean is if a user add something to textfield and press send (which means adding it to my database), I want to accept or decline it to my database, before adding it there!

**My button action:**

```
@IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        //Saving item to database
        if commentTextField.text !=  "" && placeLabel.text != "Location"
        {

            let place = placeLabel.text

            let key = dbRef!.child("placeLabel").childByAutoId().key


            dbRef!.child(place!+"/placeLabel").child(key).setValue(place)
            dbRef!.child(place!+"/comment").child(key).setValue(commentTextField.text)
            dbRef!.child(place!+"/rating").child(key).setValue(ratingControl.rating)

            commentTextField.text = ""
            //alert
            createAlert(title: "Thank you!", message: "Review submitted.")
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }else{
            //alert
            createAlert(title: "Why don't write a review?", message: "Please write a review.")
        }

    }
```

Comment: If my answer helped, accept it pls.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you currectly, then **First way**:

> 1) Add extra field like `isAccepted`
>
> 2) Add new value to your node, but show only if `isAccepted == true`.
>
> 3) If `false` show some `UIView` for approving.

**Second way:**

> 1) You should create additional node with name like `Suggested
>   actions`
>
> 2) Let user add to this node
>
> 3) Check from your user this node and accept/decline.
>
> 4) If accepted - add to final node

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a more detailed answer?

Comment: @AlexAndreadis what details do you want from me?:) For example, if you have table view, you will have 2 prototypes of cells. First is approvements, second is data. And if post was approved, it will be moved to data. Like this. It depending on your logic. But it's another question. Answer for current question I've already given I think. Hope that helps

Comment: Yes that is the logic, this is the thought! i agree, but my question is about how to do it programmatically. That's why i provided code.

Comment: @AlexAndreadis do u want us to write full controller code for you or what? Code that you have posted doest not contain no one structure like tableview etc. And this is not short answer.... Ok, It's your decision

Comment: @AlexAndreadis me and Mr. Nivesh Shastri gave u an idea. Try to implement it. No one will write you full controller code, I think. Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to enable offline capability of firebase database. It will enhance the processing and you don't need to handle this.This will achieve with one line of code only.