# Is there a way to approve the data being inserted by the user into firebase database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an android activity that would allow the user to insert data into my firebase database. My question is how do I put the data inserted by the user on hold until an admin approves it?

I have seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978219/firebase-database-saving-data-after-approvement) but I really don't know how to do that. I am new to firebase and it is really good for me. Please guide me sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a node in your database with name `unapprovedData`, and insert all the data inside it first.

Then you may provide that data to the device of the admin by retrieving data from Firebase to his/her device. And you can provide them a checkbox or a button that says approve or disapprove.

If they hit the button with approve, you can transfer the data from `unapprovedData` to the node where all the approved data is present.

I am giving you a sample JSON structure here, you may take inspiration from it.

```json
FirebaseUnique
|
 --- UnapprovedData
| |
|  -- data1
| |
|  -- data2
| | 
|  -- data3
|  
 --- ApprovedData
 |
  -- data4
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is a very big help for me.

Comment: @TheodoreFlores no worries, glad to help :) Cheers!